# Django - how to use many variables in a template tag value

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to add two variables as the value on an input tag but the syntax I am currently using only renders the first variable. How can I make both variables show up?
Current code
loan={
amount": 200000,
"due_date": "12/12/2021",
"currency": "UGX
}

```
<input class="block" id="address" name="address" type="number" value="{{ loan.amount }} {{ loan.currency }}">
```

This currently outputs nothing

Comment: Your loan object doesn't have a key "currency" but it's the second variable you're trying to use - where is `{{ loan.currency }}` supposed to be populated?

Comment: Can you show your view ? Or the value of loan, beacause as @lain mentioned, you don't have a `currency` key in the `loan` dict

Comment: Change it to, say, `/{{ loan.currency }}/`. I'm betting `loan.currency` is undefined and rendering as an empty string. Or possibly it actually is an empty string in the `loan` instance.

Comment: I have updated the loan object. The page renders a template error of pointing to the two vairables